# Loading script in innerHTML: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript

The error I get here  `while (++i < children.length)`. I am a bigenner, I don't undestand, if I should replace all my nodes with this line? `document.getElementById('filter-content')` I actually tried to define a variable node, but get an error too ... Code below

```
onFinish = value => {
    function nodeScriptReplace(node){
      if ( nodeScriptIs(node) === true ) {
        node.parentNode.replaceChild( nodeScriptClone(node) , node );
      }
      else {
        var i = -1, children = node.childNodes;
        while ( ++i < children.length ) {
          nodeScriptReplace( children[i] );
        }
      }
        return node;
      }

      function nodeScriptClone(node) {
        const script  = document.createElement("script");
        script.text = node.innerHTML;

        let i = -1, attrs = node.attributes, attr;
        while ( ++i < attrs.length ) {                                    
          script.setAttribute( (attr = attrs[i]).name, attr.value );
        }
        return script;
      }

      function nodeScriptIs(node) {
        return node.tagName === 'SCRIPT';
      }

    fetch(`filter?layout=false&q[city_id_eq]=${this.state.value}`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(content => nodeScriptReplace(document.getElementById('filter-content').html = content));
};
```

Comment: `Cannot read property length of undefined` means you are trying to read the length of a null variable. Please make sure that your variables are not `null` before performing any operation on it. Read the error stack trace and fix the line number shown on the trace.

Comment: `node.childNodes` is undefined.. console.log(node) and see what is returned before the while loop

Comment: node is not defined. Does this mean, I need to define node as document.getElementById('filter-content')? But i tried and it didn't render anything at all...

Comment: so if even node is undefined, it means that `document.getElementById('filter-content').html = content` is either null or undefined and it would kind of make sense, because ur passing in a value(trying to) but then ur assigning at the same time

Comment: but if I do this `.then(content => nodeScriptReplace(document.getElementById('filter-content')[0]))` - it's still not working